# Unable to send Mail using Mobile Network

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am using GmailSender in my android application. I want to send background mails without user interaction. Senders mail id and password is hardcoded. I am able to send mail through WIFI network but not through Mobile network.

I am getting the following Error:

```
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtI
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534-5.7.14 qg52WWNjNZOHmj7IBmGfCHrdfoS-4LdRTeBtNAAQnY4tqO4SAXeycCq6qpkW
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534-5.7.14 9ucShyDKruN9FT10S3BOkCLwhbC5ERe-rGgzc01CQTSGQ6OjGvGX_DITw24wqGtqJH_1zw
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534-5.7.14 hy_a1mL3D4ekerSFekwYj42iRo-6ZUNwQait3VzJXJyNwoC3HEr8sV8-oZuHJFNGl6mHF9
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534-5.7.14 XapTjLkcfsCwcjelLFsZITtPABkoE> Please log in via your web browser and
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534-5.7.14 then try again.
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534-5.7.14  Learn more at
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 o22sm5125389pfa.15 - gsmtp
06-23 13:49:02.483  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ [ 06-23 13:49:02.501 12617:12623 W/art      ]
Suspending all threads took: 16.916ms
06-23 13:49:02.503  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
06-23 13:49:02.503  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
06-23 13:49:02.503  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
06-23 13:49:02.504  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
06-23 13:49:02.504  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
06-23 13:49:02.504  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
06-23 13:49:02.504  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
06-23 13:49:02.504  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at com.android.sync.mail.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:116)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at com.android.sync.ui.SyncFragment$MailAsyncTask.doInBackground(SyncFragment.java:476)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at com.android.sync.ui.SyncFragment$MailAsyncTask.doInBackground(SyncFragment.java:431)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-23 13:49:02.505  12617-12686/com.android.sync.client.view W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

According to this i allowed access for all apps in that gmail settings. But still no luck.

This is my GmailSender Class:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;
String ContentType = "";

static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password,IVYApplication ivyapp) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
    C_MailBO mailBO = ivyapp.configHelper.getMailBO();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", mailBO.getProtocol());
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailBO.getHost());
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", mailBO.getAuth());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", mailBO.getSmtpport());
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", mailBO.getSocketfactoryport());
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", mailBO.getSocketfactoryclass());
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", mailBO.getSocketfactoryfallback());
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", mailBO.getQuitwait());

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipient, String ccrecipent, File file) throws Exception {

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(ccrecipent));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // 3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message content
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.setText(body);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);

        List<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        uriList.add(Uri.fromFile(file));

        for (int i = 0; i < uriList.size(); i++) {
            // 4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object
            // to this object
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = uriList.get(i).getPath().substring(uriList.get(i).getPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, uriList.get(i).getPath().length());// change
            // accordingly
            System.out.println("filename " + filename);
            FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(uriList.get(i).getPath());
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
            // 5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to
            // this object
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
        }

        // 6) set the multiplart object to the message object
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // 7) send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("message sent....");
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter arg0) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setLoginTimeout(int arg0) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> arg0) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String arg0, String arg1)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Too much spam(or too much new devices) and they(google) enable captcha for you ... The solution is in the exception itself... Seems like you didn't even read it

Comment: i read it.. i logged into the browser and given access but nothing works..

Comment: *i read it* ... obviously not all, from the exception: 
[Make sure your mail app isn't set to check for new email too often. If your mail app checks for new messages more than once every 10 minutes, the app’s access to your account could be blocked.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754)

Comment: Thanks but no this is to send mail alone.. not to receive..

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), then remove ByteArrayDataSource since it's [included in JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html).  The general [Gmail instructions are in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail), and see these instructions for use of [OAuth2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2), which you might need to overcome your problem.